# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Observable<Object>>' angular service call

Tags: angular, async-await, subscribe

trying to make a service call in Angular on init for a component, the server I'm fetching data from takes a bit to respond and as such I am trying to use promises to assign the data returned to this.stats in my component

when trying to write the function, I'm getting -> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Observable>' on my 'subscribe' (in my component) I've tried to rewrite the function several ways and I wasn't able to get the error to change, I'm probably just doing this fundamentally wrong, but couldn't find anything to match my exact case here so figured I'd reach out for any possible explanations.... maybe some type casting I need to change?

component

```
export class StatsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() stats: any
  @Output() onUpdateStats: EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter()

  constructor(private specsService: SpecsService) { }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.specsService.getStats().subscribe((response) => {this.stats=response});
  }

  updateStats(){
    console.log(this.stats)
    this.onUpdateStats.emit()
    
  }

}
```

services.ts

```
 async getStats():Promise<Observable<Object>>{
    return await this.http.get(`http://localhost:8888/fetchStats`)
   
  }
```

Comment: You'd have to await to get the observable _then_ subscribe, but why are you mixing observables and promises like that? Just _return the observable_.

Comment: It's hard to be 100% clear based on what you've posted but I think `getStats` should just be: `return this.http.get('http://localhost:8888/fetchStats');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't mix promises with observables. Angular comes with RxJs which use the Observable design pattern, you should definitely stick to it and avoid using async/await.

Service :

```
getStats():Observable<Object>{
   return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8888/fetchStats`)
}
```

Component :

```
export class StatsComponent {
  @Output() onUpdateStats: EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter();
  stats: Observable<Object>;

  constructor(private specsService: SpecsService) {
      this.stats = this.specsService.getStats();
  }

  updateStats(){
    console.log(this.stats)
    this.onUpdateStats.emit()
  }

}
```

Comment: It's pretty common to mix observables and promises. RxJs even has a `toPromise` method?

Comment: Yes but what the point to use promise here (and most of the time) when you can use observables only ? RxJs is much more powerful and flexible than promises.

Comment: In your opinion

Comment: The problem is that in the example, Observables and Promises are mixed.
So if want to use await, you can call: 
 `await myObservable.toPromise()`

Or you can call subscribe() on the observable. 
It doesn't make sense to wrap an observable in a promise: 
`Promise<Observable<Object>>`

RxJs is my preference, but promises can be useful every now and then.

Comment: thank you all, I did some deeper diving on observables to understand how they work/ benefits vs promises etc, I was able to resolve by reducing everything to only use observable types